# Solving for $x$ in $f(f(x))=g(f(x))$ where $f(x)=3x$, $g(x)=x^2-3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

[image: Function Question]

What I assumed they were asking is what values of x allows that equation to be true. If so then

$f(3x) =3(3x) = 9x$

$g(3x) =(3x)^2 -3 = 9x^2 -3$

$9x = 9x^2 -3$

I saw a quadratic and went on to solve it but that doesnt give the correct answer so maybe I did the wrong thing. I am a bit stuck.

Edit:
The answer according to the book is -0.5 and 1.5 but i am getting -0.26 and -1.26

Comment: You made a small mistake. $(3x)^2 = 9x^2$ not $3x^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(f(x))=f(3x)=9x$

$g(f(x)=g(3x)=(3x)^2-3=9x^2-3$

Therefore, $f(f(x))=g(f(x)) \implies 9x=9x^2-3 \implies 0=3x^2-3x-1$

So $x=\frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{\frac{7}{3}}}{2}$

Comment: How did you get that ? I am getting 1.26 and -0.26

Comment: Those are the same values. If you work out the estimation of the number I provided, then you get $x \approx 1.2638, -0.26376$. Also, I got those numbers through the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $g(3x) = (3x)^2 - 3 \neq 3x^2 - 3$. You forgot to square the $3$.

Comment: Oh thank you but i am a bit confused, The book says the answer is -0.5 and 1.5 but when I plot the graph i am not sure how exactly are they getting those answers. http://prntscr.com/dail75

Comment: Are you sure your book says that? Those aren't the correct solutions.

Comment: @user2861799 The points that were highlighted in the link are not the intersection points. I'm not sure what they are other than just values of the functions, but they do _not_ represent the intersections.

Answer (score 0):

$$ f(f(x)) = g(f(x)) \rightarrow f(y) = g(y) \; \& \; y=f(x) $$

$$ y - (y^2-3) =0 \rightarrow y = \begin{cases} y & = \frac{3}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{21}}{2} \\ y & = \frac{3}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{21}}{2} \end{cases} $$

$$ y = f(x) \rightarrow x = \frac{y}{3} $$